# If every ascending chain of ideals leading up to an ideal stabilises, is the ideal finitely generated?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

I'm a fourth-year undergraduate currently studying a master's degree. In the last couple of weeks, I have been wondering about the interaction of the Noetherian condition with the prime ideals of a commutative ring with $1$.

While working on a result I found, I came across the following condition for an ideal $\mathfrak{b}$ organically:

> Every ascending chain of ideals $(\mathfrak{b}_i)_I$ *converging upwards* (or *leading upwards*) to the ideal $\mathfrak{b}$ stabilises. $(*)$

where the italicised terms are my own coinage, meaning that $(\mathfrak{b}_i)_I$ is an ascending chain of ideals* and $\bigcup_I \mathfrak{b}_i = \mathfrak{b}$, which it is also convenient to denote by $\mathfrak{b}_i \uparrow \mathfrak{b}$.

It is clear that $\mathfrak{b}$ finitely generated implies $(*)$. However, I am not sure about the converse.

**Question**: if $\mathfrak{b}$ satisfies $(*)$, is $\mathfrak{b}$ finitely generated? (AC allowed.)

There is an "obvious" proof to attempt. Suppose not, and let $\mathfrak{b}$ have generating set $\{r_j\}_J$ with $J$ infinite. Then, let $(J_i)$ be a chain of subsets (with respect to inclusion) converging to $J$, and set:

$$\mathfrak{b}_i = \langle J_i \rangle$$

However, this runs into two possible issues. Firstly, not every ideal has a minimal generating set, so it is not clear from this idea alone that the ascending chain does not stabilise. Secondly, if $J$ is uncountable, even with the well-ordering principle, it is not clear (to me, at least) how to construct the $(J_i)$ adequately. Nevertheless, it is perhaps helpful to note that any counterexample $\mathfrak{b}$ cannot be countably generated, and it must not have a minimal generating set.

Overall, I am quite unsure about whether or not $(*)$ implies finite generation. The only other remark that I can make is that I know that the jump between finite and uncountable is not unprecedented (cardinalities of power sets, dimensions of Banach spaces, etc.), so I'm not sure that even what I've found is an effective heuristic for intuition.

Thank you for reading.

**Edit**: for this question, $(\mathfrak{b}_i)_I$ is an ascending chain of ideals whenever $I$ is a total order and $i \le j \implies \mathfrak{b}_i \subseteq \mathfrak{b}_j$. We say that it stabilises if there exists some $i$ such that $\mathfrak{b} = \mathfrak{b}_i$.

Comment: What is an ascending chain for you?  I.e. is $I$ allowed to be an arbitrary ordinal?

Comment: @user19232801 Yes, that is the definition I was using. But actually, I would also be interested in the answer if $I$ is only allowed to be countable too.

Comment: Please specify what an ascending chain is for you in the question and when it stabilizes. The usual meaning of an ascending chain allows any linear order. Maybe it is better to choose a different name.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I have added my definitions at the end of the post.

Comment: @A.S. the point is that allowing only countable ordinals changes the answer.

Comment: @YCor Yes, I understood this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More generally, we can ask: if $M$ is some $R$-module which is not the union of a chain of proper submodules, is $M$ finitely generated? This is in fact true. This was already asked at [SE/246182](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246182), and even though the proof posted there is not correct, a comment refers to

> Bodo Pareigis, *Categories and functors*, Academic Press, 1970

The result is Corollary 1 in section 4.10 (page 205). The proof is not really easy. The main technical ingredient is Lemma 1 in section 4.7, the proof uses ordinal numbers.

Comment: IMO, the difficulty arises only because concreteness of the abelian category is not assumed; lattice of submodules continuously embeds into distributive lattice of subsets, therefore any chain of submodules admits a cofinal totally ordered subchain. This question is also posed as an excercise in "Algebraic K-theory" by H. Bass — module is f.g. iff every totally ordered chain of proper submodules has a proper union; and if it's true only for countable chains, then module is "$\Bbb N$-compact", i.e. Hom from it commutes with direct _sums_.

Answer (score 6):

Let $M$ be a module (over anything). Let $\alpha$ be the smallest cardinal of a generating subset. Let $f:\alpha\to M$ be a map whose image generates $M$. For $\beta\in\alpha$ let $M_\beta$ be the submodule $\mathrm{Span}(f(\gamma):\gamma\le\beta)$. Let $I$ be the set of modules $M_\beta$ when $\beta\in\alpha$. Then $I$ is a chain.

The union of $I$ is $M$ (easy since $f(\alpha)$ generates).

If $M$ is not finitely generated, $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal. Hence for $\beta\in\alpha$, $\beta+1$ has cardinal $<\alpha$, so $M_\beta\neq M$. Thus $M$ is the union of a chain of proper submodules.

Comment: ...You omitted the only hard part of the question: that finitely generated modules do not admit infinite exhausting filtrations.

Comment: @DenisT I read the question as (something) implies f.g. Not the converse (which is trivial anyway).

Comment: I am glad that there is an easy proof after all.

Comment: Thank you for your elegant proof. I accepted Martin's answer as he provided the first resolution to the question.